# How to "convert" a simple flash project to HTML5 using OpenFL

Tags: html, flash, haxe, openfl

I have to "convert" some flash projects to HTML5/JS but I don't really know how I can do it :(

This flash projects are little "activities" like this one :
https://www.brainpop.com/artsandmusic/artconcepts/cameras/activity/#=standard

I did some research about it, but i'm a bit lost...

I found other people asking the same question and a lot of responses are to use Haxe/OpenFL and as3hx (https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/as3hx) but I don't really understand how to proceed...

Is it possible to load a .swf file with openfl-swf to create a similar .html file ?
Should I convert AS3 to Haxe3 with as3hx ?
Is there a simple way to just get a graphic render of this activities without any interactivity so I can add manually input text field ?

I never used ActionScript or Haxe before.

If someone has any suggestions i'll be glad to hear it :)

I hope my explanations are clear, english is not my first language, so excuse me for any mistake.

Cheers !

Comment: Blindly converting anything is unlikely to reap the benefits you're looking for; I expect you'll need some understanding of the code.  That said, you may also want to look into http://as3js.org/ which is a transpiler for moving AS3 to Javascript.  This doesn't address stage objects, but if your fla file is pure code, it may be the more direct solution.

Comment: I don't really want to blindly convert it, but i have to find a solution to be as fast as i can to convert it, because i'll probably have hundred of projects like this one to convert. I'm gonna have a look at as3js, thank you for your suggestion :)
Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

as3hx will convert only as3 code to haxe openfl and may well need hand tweaking. To make the code more flexible try to avoid extending Sprite then potentially it will be easier to use your activity logic in more webgl accelerated haxe solutions like Kha and Luxe.

You probably need clean seperation of the code and the onscreen layout.
To run a fla swf that is mostly graphics in openfl you need to use the haxelib https://github.com/openfl/swf, it can be quite fiddly getting to different children or frames and the gradients are not perfect, just remember when using it that it's not the same as accessing a child normally your using a structure that is a bit different to do that.

Alternatively you may find flump useful it can be used with openflump.
https://github.com/SavedByZero/openflump exports from flash IDE.
It converts lots of your graphics to png sequences in nested structures, it would probably be worth rebuilding textfields yourself.

Openfl js can be slow I suggest you do some tests before committing to a solution, since Kha or Luxe may provide you a more shader modern approach to graphics than a flash emulation api solution, but then all you assets largely need to be images.

I doubt if there is any ideal way but getting your logic in Haxe is really good idea because then you can do c++, c#, js etc..  The first step if you choose openfl is to perhaps to try just porting parts of your code to haxe and then use them as a swc in your current projects this will allow you to gradually check your conversion and fix an issues easily within a haxe flash approach prior to trying to do the same in html haxe.  You may find the swf library is not ideal for html5 and that png's are the way to go, Animate now provides export png sequence which I have used in starling as3.  Another approach to consider is the away3d plugin for Animate it can convert flash timeline into typescript away3d (2D ) that you can control with javascript code ( even haxe you may have got from as3hx if you remove some of the flash specific haxe and adjust it to work with the away3d 2d but I guess it could be very complex ).